# how to avoid deep clone in my wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, clone, freeze

I have a PointCollection object which i want to clone into another object but the problem is - I have to use Freeze and clone each Point in my PointCollection which takes alot of valuable procceccing time which i cant afford in my app.

The way im doing it is :

```
    pointCollection.Freeze();
Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() => MainWindow.SpectrumList[antennaName].spectrumViewModel.AntennaPoints = pointCollection.Clone()));
```

is there a possible different way (parhaps by sending a referense, although ive tried that and it throws me an exception) to do this?

Comment: Please post a bit more about your problem.  What is the exception being thrown?  When you say "send a reference," do you mean create a new collection with references to the original points, or are you passing a reference to the collection itself?  Where does the original PointCollection exist?  Is it on another thread?  Why do you need to clone in the first place?

Comment: i have a server which sends alot of points to the client in real-time nonstop and i have to organize the points ( i have a list of 9 different usercontrols which should receive a different PointCollection each ) and when the PointCollection is organized correctly im sending it to the correct usercontrol and the cloning proccess takes up alot of time. i tried to send a reference of the organized PointCollection to the usercontrol instead of cloning but i got - "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." exception.

Comment: @SlavaZoref it sounds like you jumped to conclusions here. Can you show more code? This problem needs to be treated holistically.

Comment: @usr which parts of my code would you like me to post?

Comment: When you are sending many points remote I guess that sending simple point arrays should be ok. Besides that you should think about compression. If you send many points to a remote destination which are mostly equal it would make sense to send only the difference points. A step further would be to use for the difference some compression algo like RLE to get most out of it. I am not sure how creating a copy of the list is your main botttleneck because sending all the data over a network is in any case much more costly.

Comment: @AloisKraus wouldnt a compression algorithm take much more time than just send the points as is? because im sending each time an array of 400 points ( each consisting of 2 floats ) and a string which insicates which usercontrol it should be sent so total would be about 3kb of data each send which is ( in today transfering speed ) nothing at all for the speed of my program ( please correct me if im wrong ).

Comment: You can access transfer in your local memory several hundred MB/s. But if you have a small internet bandwidth with e.g. 1 MB/s there is a difference. If your problem is on the server side that copying local data is too costly then how do you transfer so much data to the client? Are you sure that this is actually your bottleneck? How did you measure it?

Comment: im not sure actualy, but this seems like the most reasonable cause.

Comment: Please use a profiler or the free one from the Windows Performance SDK. To get full call stacks you should have .NET 4.5 installed. http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/12/19/151604.aspx for a intro and this http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/12/28/151662.aspx for a detailed CPU analysis as an example.

Comment: oh, thanks! ill check this out, you might be right and the performence issue is coming from somewhere else.